# how JavaScript recursive function works when assigned to variable?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Hi I am new to JavaScript but i don't understand how recursive function works when assigned to a variable. Below code should have only two outputs but instead it has 3 output.

```js
function capitalizeFirst(array) {
  if (array.length === 1) {
    return [array[0][0].toUpperCase() + array[0].substr(1)];
  }
  const res = capitalizeFirst(array.slice(0, -1));
  console.log(res);
  return res;
}
console.log(capitalizeFirst(['car', 'taco', 'banana']));
```

As I think: first capitalizeFirst(array.slice(0, -1)); will work as recursive function and return ['Car'] as result to res, then console.log(res) print result then return statement return res to function so final console.log(capitalizeFirst(['car', 'taco', 'banana'])); should return ['car'] as a result. So in console screen I should get two output but instead I am getting three why?

Comment: `if (array.length === 1)` is false twice, so it continues twice to the `console.log(res)` statement, plus one final `console.log(capitalizeFirst(..))`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**: Your recursive function outputs the first element of the array as a capitalized word equal to the length of your array - 1 AND this result is outputted. The total outputs being equal to the array length.

Your array has a length of 3 and in your base case will return an array. So res will be outputted 2 times within the recursive function and once outside.

If you have an array that is just `[Car]`, then the recursive function will return `[Car]` which will be outputted.

If you have an array that is `[car, taco]`, it will first go through the recursive function, then shrink down to `[Car]` and since this is the base case, will return `[Car]`. This means that within the recursive function, res = `[Car]`. And since you have `console.log(res)` and `return res`, `[Car]` will be outputted within the recursive function and then outputted outside.

In the scenario with an array length of 3, it will output `[Car]` twice within since the recursive function continues until the length is 1 (Meaning that it will hit the `console.log` twice). And finally when res is returned, it is `[Car]` which will be outputted by the outside `console.log`.